# how to hide id from URL laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

i have this url :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/deliverer/4
```

i want it like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/deliverer/
```

this is my function :

```
    public function show($id)
    {

//        $userhash->hashids->encode($id);
        $user=User::find($id);

        return view('deliverer.profile')->with('user',$user);
    }
```

and this is my route

```
Route::get('deliverer/{id}', 'deliverer\DelivererController@show')->name('profile');
```

and this in view

```
<a          href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/deliverer/{{ Auth::user()->id }}" >
                    <i class="nc-icon nc-single-02"></i>
                    <p>Profile</p>
                </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, that what you're trying to accomplish is to view the current authenticated user's profile, then you should follow the steps below:

First you have to modify the route and remove the {id} from the URL, like this:

```
Route::get('deliverer', 'deliverer\DelivererController@show')->name('profile');
```

Then, inside the controller you have to remove the $id param from the show() method and change the method to get the id from the authenticated user.

```
public function show($id)
{
//        $userhash->hashids->encode($id);
    $user = \Auth::user();

    return view('deliverer.profile')->with('user',$user);
}
```

And of course, you have to remove the Auth::user()->id() from the view route, and perhaps use the named route instead of hardcoding it, like so:

```
<a href="{{ route('profile') }}">
    <i class="nc-icon nc-single-02"></i>
    <p>Profile</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're just trying to hide id's so users can guess the next number or try to pull up records they shouldn't.

Have you looked into UUID's? Example here: (https://dev.to/wilburpowery/easily-use-uuids-in-laravel-45be) That might be a solution.

Also, if you are worried that someone might tamper with URL to pull records, you should look into securing up your models. Do a check to see if the user should have access to that particular record. Many ways to accomplish that.

Comment: Use Ramsey uuid, create column uuid, insert uuid from uuid4 Ramsey function, instead of Id replace by uuid in url route and in function route use the where close instead of find.

Answer (score 0):

You can use token or configure a middleware, or as you did you can hash or crypt the id and make the verification after the call

The url will be like that :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/deliverer/?id=aze45a8sd54q
```